# Triggering a lexical.js mentions menu programatically when clicking on a mention

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

##### What I need

Let's start with [The mentions plugin](https://codesandbox.io/s/lexical-mention-plugin-example-ojn42n?from-embed=&file=/src/plugins/MentionsPlugin.tsx:7215-7229) taken from [the docs](https://lexical.dev/docs/demos/plugins/mentions).

I would like to enhance if with the following functionality:

1. Whenever I click on an existing `MentionNode`, the menu gets rendered (like it does when `menuRenderFunction` gets called), with the full list of options, regardless of queryString matching
2. Selecting an option from menu replaces said mention with the newly selected one

Is there a way to implement this while leaving `LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin` in control of the menu?

Thank you for your time

---

##### What I've tried

I figured that maybe I could achieve my desired behaviour simply by returning the right `QueryMatch` from `triggerFn`. Something like this:

```js
const x: FC = () => {
  const nodeAtSelection = useNodeAtSelection() // Returns LexicalNode at selection

  return (
    <LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin<VariableTypeaheadOption>
      triggerFn={(text, editor) => {
        if ($isMentionsNode(nodeAtSelection)) {
          // No idea how to implement `getQueryMatchForMentionsNode`, 
          // or whether it's even possible
          return getQueryMatchForMentionsNode(nodeAtSelection, text, editor)
        }

        return checkForVariableBeforeCaret(text, editor)
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

I played around with it for about half an hour, unfortunately I couldn't really find any documentation for `triggerFn` or `QueryMatch`, and haven't really made any progress just by messing around.

I also thought of a potential solution the I think would work, but feels very hacky and I would prefer not to use it. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### So here is my "dirty" solution that should work, but feels very hacky:

I could basically take the function which I provide to `menuRenderFn` prop and call it manually.

Let's say I render the plugin like this:

```js
const menuRenderer = (
   anchorElementRef,
   { selectedIndex, selectOptionAndCleanUp, setHighlightedIndex }
) => { /* ... */}
    
return (
   <LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin menuRenderFn={menuRenderer}  /* ... other props */ />
)
```

I could then create a parallel environment for rendering `menuRenderer`, something like this:

```js
const useParallelMenu = (
  menuRenderer: MenuRenderFn<any>,
  allOptions: TypeaheadOption[],
  queryString: string
) => {
  // I could get anchor element:
  // 1. either by using document.querySelector("." + anchorClassName)
  // 2. or by extracting it from inside `menuRenderFn`:
  //    menuRenderFn={(...params) => {
  //       extractedRef.current = params[0].current;
  //       return menuRenderer(...params)
  //    }}
  const anchorEl = x
  const [selectedIndex, setHighlightedIndex] = useState(0)

  const nodeAtSelection = useNodeAtSelection() // Returns LexicalNode at selection

  const selectOptionAndCleanUp = (option: TypeaheadOption) => {
    // Replace nodeAtSelection with new MentionsNode from `option`
  }

  return () =>
    $isMentionsNode(nodeAtSelection) &&
    menuRenderer(
      anchorEl,
      {
        selectedIndex,
        setHighlightedIndex,
        selectOptionAndCleanUp,
        options: allOptions
      },
      queryString
    )
}
```

On paper, this seems like a viable approach to me... but I would really prefer not to have to do this and instead let `LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin` manage the state of my menu, as it is intended to do.

Comment: Did you figure out a better way of doing it?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/ We actually ended up leaving this functionality out entirely, hoping we can implement this cleanly in future versions of Lexical